# "Your credentials aren't allowed" - Google+ API - Production

Tags: python, django, google-api, django-socialauth, social-authentication

I recently implanted the connection with facebook and google on my local server, and everything worked.
But, when I tried to do it in production, the connection with google returns: "Your credentials aren't allowed". (Facebook works)

I don't know why, because i'm pretty sure that my application is confirmed by Google.
Do you have some ideas ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, I used a wrong key on settings.py